# How do I disable a checkbox in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagriview inside with only checkbox in 5 rows and 10 column.
How do I disable the single checkbox, so that the user can not click on the checkbox, which must remain in the state in which it is located.

Another thing, how do you widen the column header, as I have enumerated fields, but when I launch the program the column is close and I have to enlarge to see the numbers.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's an [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the Checkbox class.  Set it to `false`.

To set the width of a column, address the [Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) you're interested in, using the indexer of the [Columns collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx), and assign the [Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width(v=vs.110).aspx) property, like this:

```
myDataGridView.Columns[columnNumber].Width = newWidth;
```